# How to get the return value from a confirm popup alert

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a popup alert.
The problem with it is that I can't get the return value.
It is because the close function is created in the function itself.

Is there a way to return the value?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dccb2fu0/1/)

HTML

```
<button id="div" onclick="popup()">START</button>

<div id="popUp">
  <div id="popUpHeader">
  </div>
  <div id="popUpBody">
    <h1 id="title"></h1>
    <p id="txt"></p>
  </div>
  <button id="popUpButton">OK</button>
  <button id="popUpYes">YES</button>
  <button id="popUpNo">NO</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
function popup() {
  var a = popupbox('Warning', 'Are you sure?', 'yesno');
  alert(a);
}

function popupbox(title, txt, type) {
  document.getElementById('popUp').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = title;
  document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = txt;

  if(type == 'ok') {
    document.getElementById('popUpButton').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('popUpButton').onclick = function () {
      document.getElementById('popUp').style.display = 'none';
      document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none';
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById('popUpYes').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('popUpNo').style.display = 'block';
    //return true;
    document.getElementById('popUpYes').onclick = function () {
      document.getElementById('popUp').style.display = 'none';
      return true;
    }
    document.getElementById('popUpNo').onclick = function () {
      document.getElementById('popUp').style.display = 'none';
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

CSS

```
#popUp {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px;
    background: white;
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 100px;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    border-top: 5px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px #999;
    z-index: 9999;
    text-align: center;
}
#popUpBody {
    margin: 3px 0px 3px 0px;
}
#popUpBody h1 {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
}
#popUpBody p {
    padding: 10px 10px 0px 10px;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*ADJUST HEIGHT ACCORDING CONTENTS*/

    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
#popUpButton {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 60px;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 60px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
#popUpYes {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 60px;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 40px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
#popUpNo {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 60px;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 110px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `prompt` ??

Comment: I'd like to use a self made promptbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the user input is given after your statements are executed, you need to use callback handlers as I have updated in the 3rd line

Updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gurvinder372/dccb2fu0/5/) for you

```
function popup(){
var a = popupbox('Warning','Are you sure?','yesno', function(){alert('yes')}, function(){alert('no')} );
  //alert(a);
}



function popupbox(title,txt,type, okCallback, noCallBack){
    document.getElementById('popUp').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = title;
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = txt;

    if(type == 'ok'){
        document.getElementById('popUpButton').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('popUpButton').onclick = function(){
            document.getElementById('popUp').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none';
      okCallback();
        }
    } else {
        document.getElementById('popUpYes').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('popUpNo').style.display = 'block';
        //return true;
        document.getElementById('popUpYes').onclick = function(){
            document.getElementById('popUp').style.display = 'none';
      okCallback();
            return true;
        }
        document.getElementById('popUpNo').onclick = function(){
            document.getElementById('popUp').style.display = 'none';
      noCallBack();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks gurvinder, I wasn't aware of a callback function. Got something to read about now.

Comment: @Ethannn happy to help

Comment: I've played around with it but it seems that it can not return a value as a variable. Is there another method?

Comment: What I actually meant is that I need a return value that I can use in the rest of the `function popup()` Is it for example possible to store the returned value in the `var a`-variable. Something else is good as well off course

Answer (score 2):

The Problem is, that your `popupbox` function returns imideatly. 
In your popupbox function you set up onclick events that have a return value. That does not influence the return value of your `popupbox` function (as the onclick function is executed asynchronously on user click ;).

If you want to be able to handle the users input you should create callback functions that are executed `onclick` event as  user gurvinder372 explains in his answer.

Comment: hello @user3656699 the callback function did the trick. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

how about using a confirm box instead of an alert to do the same function with an IF statement ?

```
 var s = confirm( 'Are you sure? :' );

  if (s == true) {

}
```

Comment: Like I said I'd like to use a customized/ self made confirm box